# A diophantine equation for the E8 knot polynomial family

Tags: nt.number-theory, qa.quantum-algebra

Let $x,y,z$ be dimensions that appear in the Clebsch-Gordan series
$x*x=1+t+u+y+z$. 
(E8 family if $t=x$ (say), but there is at least another family. E.g. B4(R4) belongs to the latter.)

With the right pick of dimension ($t,u,y,z$ are not equivalent!) I got the following diophantine equation:

$$\eqalign{-27(-1+x)x^2(2+x)^2y+54x(2+x)^2y^2+9(-1+x)x^2(2+x)^2z\cr-24(-4+x)(-1+x)x(2+x)yz
+16(-1+x)(2+x)(8+x)y^2z\cr-18x^2(2+x)z^2+48(-4+x)xyz^2-32(8+x)y^2z^2=0\cr}$$

(No rational solutions please, as these are dimensions. I don't exclude negative $x,y,z$ for now, though.)
Solving after $y$, $$x(36x+36x^2+9x^3-32z+16xz+16x^2z-32z^2)=a^2$$ ($a$ is still integer) and solving that after $z$, $$2x^2(2+x)^3(1+2x)=2a^2x+b^2$$ ($b$ is also integer.)

I'm stuck here. Were this a hunt for rational solutions, I'd set $a=x(x+2)c$ and $b=x(x+2)d$ and use the standard method for Pythagorean triangles afterwards. But I'm not sure $c$ and $d$ are integers (even constraining to the actual solutions like E8(R1),...), and the Pythagorean parametrization usually also is done with rationals.

Can you still give a parametrization $x=f(p,q)$, $y=g(p,q)$, $z=h(p,q)$ with integer $p,q$? (As I said, with rational $p,q$ this is trivial, in fact I started from that!) This should be elementary number theory...but it's already too high for me.

Comment: I'm a little confused and think there might be a typo somewhere.  How do you get to something like Pythagorean triangles when there's an extra x floating around on the a^2 term?

Comment: Tex, please. This is unreadable.

Comment: Putting things in tex is easy here, you just put dollar signs around the expressions, or double dollar signs if you want display equations (which you should for some of your larger expressions).  Fortunately tex is very easy to use, and all of your expressions are already valid tex expressions.

Comment: Also, one has to be careful when using the symbol "*" as it is typically used to italicize a word or a sentence.

Comment: I have aTeXed the question. If I damaged anything, feel free to edit. 

Comment: THX for the TEXing. I'm still a n00b (but I looked at the
source code and somewhen I learn.) @Noah: Somewhere a "2"
got lost. Now (after c and d were introduced) you factor
4x^2-c^2 and progress in the usual way. 
@Bruce: I will study that, it looks helpful. (I should point
out that I naturally don't work with Lie groups, but just
with skein diagram tricks, and first have to learn how to
translate the results back to Lie group language. The
results seem to be essentially the same; I perused 
Cvitanovic's "Birdtracks".
P.S.: I would be glad if the equation has only finitely many solutions.

Comment: I'm still confused about the x.  One of the three terms has an odd number of x's, and the other two have an even number of x's.  So you can't turn it into a pythagorean theorem setup just by changing variables, right?

Comment: Well, enough to linearize:
(2x+c)(2x-c)=gx+h (g, h some mess independent of x)
2x+c=(gx+h)/i
2x-c=i
Solve after x and c, done. In my original variables:
x=-((-3+2*p)*(-3+2*r))/(2*p*r)
y=(3*(-3+2*p)*(-3+2*r))/(8*p*r*(-1+p+r))
z=(9*(-1+p)*(-3+2*r)*(-3+2*p+2*r))/(8*p^2*(p-r)*r)
(Can I TeX comments too? :-)
But p and r are rationals and I have even less ideas
how to restrict them with a divisibility argument.

The Lie algebra approach is more restrictive (e.g. 189+154+20+36+1=20^2 is valid but really F4 in disguise) 
- but if the diophantic has only finite many solutions
I can do without.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find some information on this in my papers:

MR1960703 (2004g:17003a)  Westbury, Bruce W.
$R$-matrices and the magic square.
 J. Phys. A  36  (2003),  no. 7, 1947--1959.

MR2029689 (2005g:18014)  Westbury, Bruce .
Invariant tensors and diagrams.
Proceedings of the Tenth Oporto Meeting on Geometry, Topology and
 Physics (2001).
 Internat. J. Modern Phys. A  18  (2003),  October, suppl., 49--82.